# Mock and Test method that contains call to final class that contains static and non static methods Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, easymock

I have a legacy code that contains the following method which I want to test. If I remove the `Collections.sort` line, then the test case would work fine. But I am trying to perform the test case with it.

```
void update(){
   <!-- Other logic-->
      Collections.sort(demographicsForms, DemographicsFormComparator.getInstance()); 
   <!-- Other logic-->
}
```

`demographicsForms`  is a Pojo class that contains basic setters and getters

And `DemographicsFormComparator` contains the following code

```
public final class DemographicsFormComparator implements Comparator<DemographicsForm> {

    public int compare(DemographicsForm demo1, DemographicsForm demo2) {
        return demo1.getType().getCdfMeaning().compareTo(demo2.getType().getCdfMeaning());
    }

    private static DemographicsFormComparator INSTANCE = null;

    public synchronized static DemographicsFormComparator getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new DemographicsFormComparator();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

So far I have tried this

```
    @Mock
    private DemographicsForm df1;
    @Mock
    private DemographicsForm df2;
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final DemographicsFormComparator mockA = PowerMock.createMock(DemographicsFormComparator.class);
        EasyMock.expect(mockA.compare(df1, df2)).andReturn(1).anyTimes();
        PowerMock.mockStatic(DemographicsFormComparator.class);
        EasyMock.expect(DemographicsFormComparator.getInstance()).andReturn(mockA).anyTimes();
        PowerMock.replayAll(mockA);
    }
```

But the above approach gives me the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call DemographicsFormComparator.compare
```

Edit 1:
Tried passing real objects for demographicform

```
    DemographicsForm df1 = new DemographicsForm();
        DemographicsForm df2 = new DemographicsForm();

        final DemographicsFormComparator mockA = PowerMock.createMock(DemographicsFormComparator.class);
        EasyMock.expect(mockA.compare(df1, df2)).andReturn(1).anyTimes();

        PowerMock.mockStatic(DemographicsFormComparator.class);
        EasyMock.expect(DemographicsFormComparator.getInstance()).andReturn(mockA).anyTimes();

        PowerMock.replayAll();
```

Still getting the unexpected call to `compare`

Comment: why in the world would you need _any_ mocking frameworks for this? Create two real instances of `demographicsForms`, pass them to that `update` method, assert the side-effects of that `update` method. And unless you show that "Other logic" in `update` - which matters, this is very hard to answer

Comment: The rest of the code contains the update logic which can be easily mocked and tested, but since my code contains this one line the mocking fails. And if i simply try to pass the objects it will throw ```Null Pointer exception for compare ```method.

Comment: that `NullPointer` is an indication that the Objects you pass into `update` don't have the fields that are supposed to be there. is it not obvious from `return demo1.getType().getCdfMeaning().compareTo(demo2.getType().getCdfMeaning())`?

Comment: I did try this as well along with it ```when(df1.getType()).thenReturn(codevalue);
  when(codevalue.getCdfMeaning()).thenReturn("test");
  when(df2.getType()).thenReturn(codevalue1);
  when(codevalue1.getCdfMeaning()).thenReturn("test");```

Comment: getType() returns an object for ```codevalue``` which has further ```getCdfMeaning()``` inside it

Comment: I never said to mock these - pass REAL instances of that. think about it: do you _really_ need to mock them?

Comment: I tried passing real objects now , but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple possibilities. None of them involves PowerMock.

1. Fill real `DemographicsForm` so they will work with the comparator. In your case, it seems the getters are too complex so it doesn't work
2. Partially mock `DemographicsForm` so that the annoying getters are mocked
3. Move the comparator to a field to inject it

---

```
public class MyClass {
     private final Comparator<DemographicsForm> comparator;
     public MyClass(Comparator<DemographicsForm> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
     }
     public MyClass() {
        this(DemographicsFormComparator.getInstance());
     }
     void update() {
         <!-- Other logic-->
         Collections.sort(demographicsForms, comparator); 
         <!-- Other logic-->
     }
```

That way you can easily mock the comparator.